# How do I extrapolate a value of oxygen particles per million from vacuum pressure Pa/torr

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, vacuum, air

If I have a box of 40 $\text{cm}^3$, with ambient pressure and oxygen, how could I extrapolate and bring down the oxygen level to say 500 ppm from an equation such as $1.33 \times 10^{-4}$ Pa ($1 \times10^{-6}$ torr) (or even different types of vacuums as that is a high rated vacuum), and how would I calculate the amount of time it takes for me to bring it down to 500 ppm?

Comment: ppm is parts per million, a concentration term.  Pure oxygen has a concentration of one million parts per million.  Are you looking for oxygen molecules per unit volume?  Please clarify.

Comment: If I want a specific concentration of oxygen, example 500 ppm, how many millibars does it to take the pressure down to, and how can I can I purchase a vacuum pump that can handle that given the equations given above and how long it would take for 40cm^3

Comment: You are misinterpreting my previous comment.  ppm is a concentration term.  Concentration is totally independent of pressure, as you can have 500 ppm at any given pressure.  This means that your question, as stated, has no answer.

Comment: So the concentration of oxygen parts per million have no effect on the oxygen content in a vacuum sealed chamber? For example for additive manufacturing ebm they use a vacuum so the powder does not oxidize then melted. How do they quantify how many millibars of pressure to drop to for to attain a level where metals don't oxidize? They don't use any inert gasses either

Comment: ppm is relevant only if there is another species present besides oxygen.   The ppm is the number of oxygen molecules present per million total molecules.

Comment: that again doesnt answer the question of how any electron beam machining/melting/welding/additive manufacturing function. Or how a vacuum sintering function work. They all use a vacuum without another inert gas to reduce the level of oxygen. For my project, I dont care about any other gasses left in there at all. How does oxygen ppm not decrease (I understand the percentage stays the same as a standard atmosphere)?

Comment: @DavidWhite sorry maybe to rephrase the question, I was talking about oxygen in a standard atmosphere has 209500ppm. By reducing the atmospheric pressure to half, do I not get half the oxygen ppm?

Comment: @AndiIacob, no.  You get the same oxygen ppm.  However, you DO get a lower partial pressure of oxygen molecules.  This means that you need to rephrase your question in terms of the partial pressure of oxygen that you need when pulling a vacuum.  Start by looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure